# *No Signal* and reduced power on custom built PC?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, troubleshooting

I just built my new PC and a few things have not been working. Here's the components and what I did...

Issues:

- [SOLVED] PC turning on/off every 10 seconds. Solved by changing the voltage on the PSU.
- [] *No Signal* to monitor 3k HDMI/Display Port and 1600x900 VGA.
- [] Seems like maybe there is low power coming off the motherboard into all of the ports. I plugged in a razer left-handed gaming mouse with LEDs and it lit up, however my razer MMO gaming keyboard--using 2 USB cables for power/LED--would not light up. I also tried plugging in a WD Elements 2TB and it detected power.

Components:

- EVGA GTX 970
- 240mm H100iV2 Hydro Series Corsair Cooler.
- Intel i7 6700k
- MSI Z170MX - Gaming 5
- Kingston 240GB SSD

  - The SSD has a pre-installed OS and firmware update pulled from another PC.
- WD Red 4TB HDD
- Intel 500GB HDD
- Sentry 725W XPlus Power
- 2x Corsair Jetflow 120mm Fans
- x1 Corsair 140mm Fan

Picture:

[image]

EDIT: I do *NOT* have a motherboard speaker for posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out one of the PCI-E power cables out of the graphics card and plugged it into a power adapter of 6-pin to 4-pin an plugged the 4-pin into the power supply and voila.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you've resolved the issue. Just to be on the safe side I would double-check everything and make sure all the cables are plugged in the proper ports and are plugged all the way firmly. I'd also run a stress test on all parts to see if something got damaged along the way so you know your system is safe.
Checking your storage drives for errors is also a good idea, especially when your are reusing them. Have in mind that having a OS from another system isn't a really good idea and a fresh install is recommended when you have a new motherboard and a CPU. You are not likely to be able to boot into the OS on the new Motherboard and CPU and if you do you are under quite high risk of having BSODs and other errors.

Post back if you need help with any of this. :)

Captain_WD.